# How can I mention someone using slack notification from bitbucket pipeline

Tags: notifications, slack-api, bitbucket-pipelines

how to send slack notification mentioning someone?

```
 - step:
        name: Send Notification to Slack
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/slack-notify:2.0.0
            variables:
              WEBHOOK_URL: 'CLASSIFIED'
              MESSAGE: '$(cat error_message.txt; printf [CLASSIFIED/$(cat folder_name.txt)/index.html] @[Someone]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need user's 'Slack Id' to mention them in slack message. The text containing the user-mention syntax is automatically converted to show the display name of the user.

```
Hey <@SlackID>, thanks for submitting your report.
```

***Mentioning users**  

A mention is a special type of reference that will provide a link to the mentioned user's profile in the published text.
If the mention is included in an app-published message, the mentioned user will also be notified about the reference.*

Documentation can be found here :

 https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#mentioning-users

Comment: Thanks for the answer, How can I BOLD the message?

Comment: https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#visual-styles